# Why is making clothes fit a 3D model so dificult in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, 3d, frontend, physics

My apologies in advance if this is not a proper question. 
I am asking this purely out of curiosity. I am growing as a developer and gaining more knowledge because of this I actually realize how little I know. 
I am definitely not expecting any form of code or solutions. I basically want the smart people in our community to explain to me in the most child-like understandable form why this is so hard.

I only found 2 questions related to this issue which I'll link. 
1: [An algorithm that automatically fits clothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560871/an-algorithm-that-automatically-fits-clothing)
2: [Modelling clothing in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247157/modelling-clothing-in-c/34649682)

My question basically boils down to this:

1:Why is making clothes fit a human 3d model such a difficult thing to implement in Javascript or similar framework?

I have seen examples where people have made a human 3D model in Javascript. Why doesn't the fashion industry have something like this so people can give their measurements and know exactly how clothes would fit them before ordering? I mean surely things like this are already present in video-games where if the character grows or shrinks so do the clothes around their body.

2:Render clothes in 3D based off a picture and necessary information.

If I understood it correctly, to make things fit on models you have to make a 3D model design for it before it can be used. But what if this 3D model was generated temporarily realtime based on specs? Is this something so heavy that it would only be available in countries with fast internet?